# Jackson 2 annotations ignored in EJB Jar with JBoss (6.2.0 GA)

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jackson

I am migrating a web app from Websphere 7 (JEE5) to JBoss EAP 6.2.0 (JEE6).  It currently works fine in Glassfish 3 & WAS.

The web interface consumes/produces JSON - so am using Jackson2 with Spring 3 MVC *MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter* to handling (de)serialisation in a simple controller class.

In JBoss I see Jackson2 annotations *@JsonProperty* etc are being ignored in the ejb module - (they are applied to JPA entities only), but **are** being applied in the web module. So responses come back with different field names for some objects in JBoss which trips up our user interface.

I've tried every permuation of `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` to no avail (see below).  I'm aware that JBoss ships with Jackson 1.x as an internal module.  However, this doesn't seem to be the problem, otherwise the web module annotations would be ignored as well ? E.g.: [Jackson annotations ignored after deployment to JBOSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683843/jackson-annotations-ignored-after-deployment-to-jboss)

The app is structured as 3 maven modules - war, ejb (jar) & the ear container.

I'm going to refactor the code to remove the annotations from the JPA entities, but really it would be good to find a coherent solution, as there are several other apps to migrate.

#### JBoss descriptor I've tried below, makes no difference.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl"/>
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl"/>
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="my-war.war">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl"/>
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl"/>
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="my-ejbs.jar">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl"/>
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl"/>
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

#### Initial Workaround (reverted now)

Whilst it does not address what the original problem was caused by, I have solved this by adding a Jackson Mixin within the web module to rename/suppress the fields concerned.  I've tested this and it works fine.

The point about all this, is that by using a Jackson Mixin, the scope of the customisation of the serialisation has been confined to the web module, and thereby avoided possible class loading issues due to *ejb-jar* sub-deployment.  No *jboss-deployment-structure.xml* is being used.

Add a Mixin

```
public interface MyMixin {


    @JsonIgnore
    String getUnwantedField();

    @JsonProperty(value = "newName")
    String getOldName();

}
```

Then in the startup of my web controller I wire in the Mixin to the Jackson ObjectMapper which is autowired into the controller and defined in my dispatcher servlet xml config.

```
 @Autowired
 private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

 @PostConstruct
    void configObjectMapper() {
        objectMapper.addMixInAnnotations(MyEjbJar.class, MyMixin.class);     
    }
```

Dispatcher servlet:

```
.
.
    <bean id="objectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tracked this down (via IDE debugger & adding logging) to different classloaders being used for the war module and ejb jar module.  This is expected default behaviour with JBoss AS 7 according to the docs.  The war uses the ***war*** ModuleLoader, and the ejb jar uses the ***ear*** ModuleLoader.

What happens is the Class for the annotation differs depending on which class loader loads the annotation.  Also see:  [similar issue on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265382/how-can-the-java-class-literal-return-different-instances-of-the-class-object)

By "differs" I mean they are the same annotation, sourced from the same jar & version, but they are not deemed equivalent according to the contract for equals, their hashcodes differ, therefore the *JacksonAnnotationIntrospector* does not locate annotations even though they show as held against the JPA POJO class.

#### Workaround

I have worked around this by making the ear ModuleLoader be a common loader for jackson 2.  I did this by making the *com.fasterxml.jackson.core databind* dependency *provided* scope in the war & ejb jar, and marking it as a normal compile scope dependency in the ear POM.

This kind of approach is sort of endorsed here [JBoss AS classloading](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-as-7/jboss-as-7-classloading/page-3) although it uses the *jboss-deployment-structure* or MANIFEST.MF to achieve pretty much the same thing.