# Jackson 2.x annotations not picking up in a separate jar project

Tags: java, json, maven, jackson, weblogic

I have an interesting problem: Jackson 2.x annotations are not picked up in a separate Maven module project on Weblogic 12.1.3 with Jersey 2.17 (JAX-RS 2.0).

My project structure is this:

```
project EAR
    --> domain JAR: contains JPA & Jackson2 annotated POJOs
    --> WAR: contains REST API
```

**If I put Jackson-annotated POJOs inside WAR, then Jackson annotations got picked up, and correct JSON output is generated.**

It might be a possible duplicate question, regarding this: [Jackson 2 annotations ignored in EJB Jar with JBoss (6.2.0 GA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763556/jackson-2-annotations-ignored-in-ejb-jar-with-jboss-6-2-0-ga), but I couldn't make it work on Weblogic.

It doesn't work in a separate (domain) jar.

I've tried different Maven solutions (skinny war, WL-specific classloading), but nothing seems to be working.

Here are the relevant details that you might find interesting...
My domain-JAR pom.xml includes the following:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My WAR contains the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>hu.dboros</groupId>
    <artifactId>restaurant-manager-domain</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My EAR contains just the war, as dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hu.dboros</groupId>
        <artifactId>restaurant-manager-backend-war</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
```

And my root pom contains the following dependencies (according to the Jersey 2.x guide):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Why is jersey-media-json-jackson marked as provided in your domain jar? It makes this jar run-time dependent on your war. Isn't it a better idea to have this dependency in default (compile) scope. Your war would also be able to pick it up since it's in jar that is included.

Comment: I've tried that too, but unfortunately got the same result...